# Default portname value in SOAP Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

Could someone clarify what is the default `portname` value in the `WSDl` file when deploying a `SOAP Web Service`? I have read the specs `JSR-181` and they state (page 14) that it is `@WebService.name +”Port”`. However I have deployed in `Glassfish` the following Web Service:

```
@WebService(name="interfaceName")
public interface SampleWSInterface 
{

    public int add(int a, int b);

    public int multipy(int a, int b);

}

@WebService(endpointInterface="com.xyz.webservicetest.SampleWSInterface")
public class SampleWS
{

    public int add(int a, int b){
        return a + b;
    }

    public int multipy(int a, int b){
        return a * b;
    }

}
```

and the WSDL file looks:

```
 <service name="SampleWSService">
    <port name="SampleWSPort" binding="tns:SampleWSPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL"/>
    </port>
  </service>
```

Am I right, that it gets the name only when defined on the `SIB` (when not refering to a `SEI`) and othewise it is `SIB + Port`?

Answer (score 0):

```
@WebService()
public class SampleWS
{}
```

port name= SampleWSPort (default)

```
@WebService(portName="myPortName")
    public class SampleWS
    {}
```

port name = myPortName (customized)